# $scope.$watch not called, but $digest already in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with a `$scope.$watch` not getting evaluated after a call to retrieve my data model. I'll explain, but for the impatient, maybe you can figure out what's going on based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3964/.

In our Angular project, we let some directives build their own data model, which is also sometimes passed down to other, contained directives. In this case, the directive building its own model is `myMessages`, and the directive to which its data is passed is `myObjects`.

The `myMessages` directive relies on a service called `messageManager` to get the messages relevant for it at any time (in our code, this is based on things like `$routeParams` values, e.g., `http://localhost/messages/34`). For my example, I just ignored the parameters and passed back the data directly.

The interesting part is that, if I comment out lines 55 and 68 (the wrapping `setTimeout` call), this code works "fine" (I put it in quotes because, well, I'm really not sure if it's *actually* using good practices or not). However, keeping the call there to simulate the HTTP request, the value of the `objects` scope variable in the `myObjects` directive's `link` method is empty, and the watch set up against the variable fails to run after 2 seconds.

I tried to trick the watch to re-evaluate by explicitly calling `$scope.$apply` both around the call to `ctrl.loadData()` and inside the actual `loadData` method, but received this error:

> $digest already in progress

Looking through the docs, it seems as though that's correct, because we're still within the Angular context when we do these calls (we're using ngResource inside a service, so it's not calling out to some jQuery context or anything strange). I just can't seem to get the watch against the `objects` variable to re-evaluate after the data has been populated, no matter what I try (including setting the third parameter to the `$scope.$watch` function to `true`).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I've created a [Plunker script](http://plnkr.co/edit/lUcCjZbsZSjye0QQLtsn?p=preview) using ngResource and it's working. Change it accordingly to match your real problem.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, Michael. I've figured out the issue I was having earlier that prevented me from adding a full example and have posted a fork of your Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5f2Ivub26KnEMhex2ztx. The reassuring / still somewhat frustrating situation is that it works as expected! I must be doing something wrong in my real code.

Comment: No problem. Can you post your actual code so we can try to figure out what's wrong with it?

Comment: I was just looking through the Plunker that I provided and my code, and they were remarkably similar. Really, there wasn't anything that I could find that was any different... except... the "true" argument that the Plunker was passing to the scope.$watch call on the "objects" scope item! My code did not have that, so I added it and it looks like it's working now. I wish Angular's documentation elaborated a bit more on that argument. There really isn't much mentioned about it in the docs, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` since `$timeout` will trigger a digest cycle to make the data available in the binding.

```
myApp.factory('messageManager', function ($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        getMessages: function () {
            var deferred, promise;

            deferred = $q.defer();
            promise = deferred.promise;

            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve({
                    messages: [{
                        firstName: 'Sam',
                        lastName: 'Rockwell',
                    }, {
                        firstName: 'Nat',
                        lastName: 'Faxon',
                    }, {
                        firstName: 'Jim',
                        lastName: 'Rash'
                    }]
                });
            }, 2000);

            return promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, sza, however, as I commented in the code, the setTimeout is only there to simulate the lack of me wanting to provide  the full ngResource code (since I can't get a working endpoint to provide the data and it's driving me nuts).

Comment: sza's answer is showing you how to correctly simulate a full ngResource call. Alternatively, you can wrap a `$scope.$apply` around the body of your `setTimeout` method.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it IS the solution to the example I originally posted. However, the Plunker created by Michael Benford in the comment to my original question (and my subsequent fork) is a more accurate example of what's going on here. The long and short of it is, I'm Doing It Wrong.